# Python code not working as expected

Tags: python

For some reason this code will not work? I have tried return 1 and break but for some reason it gives me a error, i would like the code to return to the beginning if the number is too long but have no ideal how to do it.

```
# Find the cube root of a perfect cube

x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
if x > 5000:
     break:
     print('too long')
 ### this code is broken ^^^^^



ans = 0
while ans**3 < x:
    ans = ans + 1
if ans**3 != x:
    print(str(x) + ' is not a perfect cube')
else:
    print('Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans))


IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> runfile('/home/dux/pyyyyy.py', wdir=r'/home/dux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/dux/pyyyyy.py", line 7
    print('wrong'):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> runfile('/home/dux/pyyyyy.py', wdir=r'/home/dux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/dux/pyyyyy.py", line 7
    break:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> runfile('/home/dux/pyyyyy.py', wdir=r'/home/dux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/dux/pyyyyy.py", line 8
    print('wrong')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> runfile('/home/dux/pyyyyy.py', wdir=r'/home/dux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/dux/pyyyyy.py", line 7
    break:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure you know [what `break` does](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)?

Comment: Are you confusing `break` for breakpoint or for `yield` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you wanted here is to check if the user enter a valid number. Try:

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    if x > 5000:
       print('too long')
    else:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

Break would stop a loop. Since your code is not in a loop, I cannot see why you would want to use it. Also, a colon is not required after break. Just so you know what break does I'll give an example.

```
count = 0
while True:
    print('Hello') #Prints Hello
    if count == 20:  #Checks if count is equal to 20
        break #If it is: break the loop
    count += 1 #Add 1 to count
```

Of course, this could be done easier by just doing a `while count < 20:` but I am illustrating a point.

Edit: Also, looking at some of the other errors you received, you **Do Not** need a colon after `print` either.